# How do I survey the caves

Tags: destiny

In one of the Guardian missions in the Cosmodrone you are asked to survey the caves. I have followed the map guide and can see the cave I am supposed to survey, but I cannot work out how to get there. There is a ramp leading up to the cave with a gap at the top but I can not make the jump on foot or with a vehicle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recon it's where you have to jump from an airplane's wing to get to? It's easiest to get up there by using a double jump. It is possible with a sparrow as well, but it's rather difficult.

Comment: As a warlock I was able to double-jump over to the ledge, did not try with the sparrow.

Comment: Be sure to use your glide at the beginning of your jump to maximize your jump height. Sprinting before the jump helps too.

Comment: If you're a hunter the opposite applies to maximum jump height/distance, you want to wait until you hit the top of your arc from your first jump and then hit the second one.